# Odd geom_bar error bars due to transforming infinite values in y-log scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, errorbar

On observations 2,3,5 I get incomplete error bars for a variable when plotting on LOG10 scale, I get the following message:

> NaNs produced Transformation introduced infinite values in continuous
> y-axis

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble::tibble(
Observation = rep(1:5,2),
Type = rep(c(rep("A",5), rep("B",5))), value = c(33046,970250,1870125,259625,3838750,196,578,323,509,215), sd = c(8538, 319023,1538959,27754,1602186,161,687,380,474,282))


ggplot(df, aes(x=Observation, y=value, fill=Type)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", 
           position=position_dodge()) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value-sd, ymax=value+sd), width=.2,
                 position=position_dodge(.9)) + theme_classic() +
   # scale_fill_manual(values=c('#999999','#E69F00'))+
  scale_y_continuous(trans='log10')
```

How could I fix it please?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `df$value - df$sd` produces negative values, which cannot be log10-transformed. I'd recommend clipping the values at some positive value. Example below uses `pmax()` to set the minimum to 1.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble::tibble(
  Observation = rep(1:5,2),
  Type = rep(c(rep("A",5), rep("B",5))), 
  value = c(33046,970250,1870125,259625,3838750,196,578,323,509,215), 
  sd = c(8538, 319023,1538959,27754,1602186,161,687,380,474,282))


ggplot(df, aes(x=Observation, y=value, fill=Type)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", 
           position=position_dodge()) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=pmax(value-sd, 1), ymax=value+sd), width=.2,
                position=position_dodge(.9)) + theme_classic() +
  scale_y_continuous(trans='log10', oob = scales::oob_squish_any)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: That is interesting. Also plan B would be only plotting the above error using ```geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value, ymax=value+sd))``` Thanks!